# Bash command stopping and not doing the third part

Tags: command-line, find

I have this command that takes any video in a folder, it converts it in `.ts` segments and creates a `m3u8` playlist.

I then need to concat them in a file `playlist.txt`, so this is what I'm doing:

```
cd /var/myfolder && find ./ -name "*.*" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:v h264 -crf 1 -flags +cgop -g 30 -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 {}.m3u8 2>&1 > /dev/null \; && ls /var/myfolder/*.m3u8 | sed "s:.*/::" | xargs -i echo file {} > /var/myfolder/playlist.txt && echo done';
```

The first and second command work (cd in folder and ffmpeg conversion) then the command `&& ls /var/myfolder/*.m3u8 | sed "s:.*/::" | xargs -i echo file {} > /var/myfolder/playlist.txt && echo done';` is not executing.

I don't understand why is not executing the 3rd command.

Comment: presumably the `find` command is returning non-zero (failure), telling the `&&` to stop.

Comment: Running the script with bash -x will also give you more debug.

Comment: I think Jeff is right, is it because Ffmpeg returns a stderr instead of a stdout maybe?

Comment: Redirecting errors to `/dev/null` and then asking us what's wrong seems extremely misdirected.

Comment: @tripleee the point is that ffmpeg does not stdout but always stderr any output.

Comment: That command line won't run, since there's an incomplete single-quoted string started at the end, just before the final semicolon. The shell would continue reading the command from the following line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use shell redirects in `find -exec`.

`xargs` defaults to `echo` ... but since you already `cd` into the directory, we can substantially simplify the last line and get rid of both `xargs` and `sed`.

```
cd /var/myfolder && 
find ./ -name "*.*" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:v h264 -crf 1 -flags +cgop -g 30 -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 {}.m3u8 \; 2>&1 > /dev/null && 
printf 'file %s\n' *.m3u8 > /var/myfolder/playlist.txt &&
echo done
```

Comment: well yeah, the redirections don't take effect just for the command started by `find -exec`, but for the whole `find`. But it doesn't matter where in the command line the redirections are set: writing `find -exec ls -ld {} \; >output` is the same as `find -exec ls -ld {} >output \;` or `>output find -exec ls -ld {} \;`